# RegEx: don't capture match, but capture after match

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

There are a thousand regular expression questions on SO, so I apologize if this is already covered. I did look first.

I have string:

```
Name Subname 11X22 88X620 AB33(20) YA5619 77,66
```

I need to capture this string: `YA5619`

What I am doing is just finding `AB33(20)` and after this I am capturing until first white space. But `AB33(20)` can be `AB-33(20)` or `AB33(-20)` or `AB33(-1)`.

My preg_match regex is: `(?<=\bAB\d{2}\(\d{2}\)\s).+?(?=\s)`

Why I am getting error when I change from `\d{2}` to `\d+`?

For final result I was thinking this regix will work but no:

`(?<=\bAB-?\d+\(-?\d+\)\s).+?(?=\s)`

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Would this help? `AB[()\d-]+\s(\S+)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/k7wx90/1)

Comment: What is the regex flavor? Try `\bAB-?\d+\(-?\d+\)\s+(\S+)`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/29qJP6/1).

Comment: @Thefourthbird your answer was brilliant, so If I understand AB[()\d-]+\s - matches my "AB33(20)" with white space and in separate group it matches any character until next white space?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks your version is working to!

Comment: @andys That is correct, I have added an explanation to my posted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With most regex flavors, lookbehind needs to evaluate to a fixed-length sequence, so you can't use variable quantifiers like `*` or `+` or even `{1,2}`.

Instead of using lookaround, you can simply match your marker pattern and then forget it with `\K`.

`AB-?\d+(?:\(-?\d+\))? \K[^ ]+`

demo: https://regex101.com/r/8XXngH/1

Comment: This version most fitted my need, it forgets the match so I don't need several groups, and how to check if there AB30 without (20) number? should I need to do like this? AB-?\d+\(-?\d+\) \K[^ ]+|AB-?\d+ \K[^ ]+

Comment: Do you mean sometimes there will be no number within the parentheses, or that both the number and parentheses might be missing?

Comment: yes it could be with parentheses and without: AB33(20) or AB33

Comment: Alright, edited the pattern to have a non-capturing group around the parentheses, followed by `?` to make it optional.

Comment: Yes this is what I need, could you explain this part: (?:\(-?\d+\))?

Comment: The `?` makes the preceding group optional (matches one or zero times), which would normally just apply to one character, so I had to make the entire thing a group. `(?: ...)` forms a non-capturing group, so the regex won't save its contents.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the language. If it is in .NET for example, it [matches](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5cbAB-%3f%5cd%2b%5c%28-%3f%5cd%2b%5c%29%5cs%29.%2b%3f%28%3f%3d%5cs%29&i=Name+Subname+11X22+88X620+AB33%2820%29+YA5619+77%2c66) due to the various length in the lookbehind.

Another solution might be to use a character class and add the character you would allow to match. Then match a whitespace character and capture  in a group matching `\S+` which matches 1+ times not a whitespace character.

```
\bAB[()\d-]+\s\K\S+
```

**Explanation**

- `\bAB` Match literally prepended with word boundary to prevent AB being part of a larger match.
- `[()\d-]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed character in the character class
- `\s` Match a whitespace char (or `\s+` to match 1 or more)
- `\K` Reset the starting point of the reported match( Forget what was matched)
- `\S+` Match in a group 1+ times not a whitespace character

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3ZBQav/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/aDaB8)

Comment: Thank you for your great answer it works too, but in first group it captures all match and in second group it shows my needed match.

Comment: @andys There are 2 matches, from which 1 is the capturing group and that contains your value. What is the programming language or tool btw?

Comment: this is php language.

Comment: @andys  Why not match [`\bYA\d+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/3ZBQav/3) If it is php you could use `\bAB[()\d-]+\s\K\S+` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/3ZBQav/2)

Comment: Thanks it would work to, thank you for you detailed version!